# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS on windows

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm Korean college student.

I succeeded in communicating between Windows and Ubuntu using the example in hydro / win_ros.
(windows - hydro, ubuntu - indigo)
If I try to run the ROS code using visual studio2015, I get a link error.
I also made various settings as shown on the wiki.
Is there a way to solve it?
Also, I would like to compile with open source code by adding the ROS code, would not it be a problem?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265223/ros-on-windows/) by [fhggty2017](https://answers.ros.org/users/30981/fhggty2017/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-30**:
`win_ros` has not been maintained for a very long time (and Hydro has been EOL for quite some time now too). Do you really *need* to use `win_ros`, or do you just need to be able to communicate with a ROS node graph from Windows? If the latter, you could look at `rosbridge_suite`, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-30**:
.. [ros.net](https://github.com/uml-robotics/ROS.NET), `rosserial_windows` or perhaps even ROS on Win10/WSL (#q238646).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS 2 does support Windows! You write your windows code in ROS 2, then use the `ros1_bridge` on your Linux system to communicate with ROS 1.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2017-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0